# Is it hidden advertisement?

Tags: discussion, edits, spam

Here is [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76120224/1556857), straightforward and precise. Here is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76120413/1556857), similar. Everybody is happy.

Then after some time an update is coming:

> Alternative solutions like AKHQ, CMAK RedPanda Console, Confluent Control Center, etc already have Docker containers for web applications that you can access from your browser rather than as desktop apps.

Considering the context, scope and quality of question, I would say that this update is:

- at least unnecessary, out of scope or similar
- at worst, a kind of hidden advertisement of payed products

I face similar updates all over the place. Especially when I'm looking for something very focused, facing blurry texts like this is annoying (of course IMHO). So personally, I would be very against such updates.

This one happened to my question/answer, so I decided to ask it finally. What are these? How should we treat them?

Comment: It's not uncommon for someone to go through posting comments/answers/edits across many questions in an attempt to promote a product. *this is not one of those cases.* but if you suspect it's occurring, you should raise a flag on the post in question with a clear explanation as to why you think something is amiss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't seems to be an advertisement. I checked his profile and it's not a spam account. He doesn't have lot of edit like that, he's mostly editing tags or making good edits.

But, this one is **not a good edit because it attempt to reply**. If it were a suggested edit, this would be declined for this reason. It should be a comment of your post (or another answer with more details).

In general, those edit should be declined. As you are the post owner, **you can revert it** by going to another revision thanks to the "Rollback" button. If it's on another post, you can flag for moderator attention, do the rollback, make another edit (and add it into review if less than 2k reputation).

Comment: Do my edits even go to a review queue anymore?

Comment: @OneCricketeer They don't as you have enough reputation (that why the edit is live). But if you didn't get enough reputation, the edit would be going into review queue and be declined as described in my answer.

Comment: Makes sense. In any case, I've modified the post being discussed

Answer (score 2):

The question itself was how to run some GUI apps as a container. You answered about networking changes and how GUI apps in containers could be done, but aren't common/easy.

The amendment was to clarify that web applications are graphical user interfaces. They do exist for Kafka, and they are very common, in containers, or elsewhere (since all the images do is start a web server). In other words, original poster is having XY Problem of wanting to run one specific GUI app. Which didn't even need to be containerized, as your answer had suggested.

Sure, a better edit would be to say "desktop application", but for anyone finding the post via a search on "Kafka + Docker + GUI", they'd have found those "advertised" solutions anyway.

Comment: If the answer isn't clear or wrong, why don't post comment to explain what's wrong? Like comment "The GUI app doesn't need to be in a container" or something?

Comment: Or post a whole other answer entirely? Good point